# apply calculation on multiple columns of each element in a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list consist of 23 elements with 69 rows and 13 columns each. And I need to apply calculation on multiple columns for each element of the list.

As a simple example, my list looks like this:

```
>list
>$`1` 
>       a       b     c 
>1    2.1    1.4    3.4 
>2    4.4    2.6    5.5 
>3    2.6    0.4    3.0 
... 

>$`2` 
>      a       b        c 
>70    5.1    4.9    5.1 
>71    4.4    7.6    8.5 
>72    2.8    3.5    6.8 
...
```

what I wish to do is something like `z = (a-b) / c`
for each element ($`1`,$`2`..., $`23`)

I tried the following code:

> for( i in 1:23) {
>   z = (list[[i]]$a - list[[i]]$b) / list[[i]]$c 
>   }

which gave me only 49 values, rather than 1566 values.

Anyone have any idea what was wrong with my code and be able to correct it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're overwriting `z` each time.  Try making `z` a list and writing `z[[i]]<- (samestuff)`

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I used the code `z = vector("list", 23)` to create a list. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with function `lapply()`. Here is example assuming that in all data frame columns have the same name.

```
ll<-list(data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=7:9),
         data.frame(a=1:3,b=6:4,c=7:9),
         data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=9:7))

lapply(ll, with, (a-b)/c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It might sound stupid but could you please clarify what are the "1:3","4:6","7:9" standing for, so that I can replicate the code you suggested with my real dataset? BTW the original data is not a data frame but a list. Thank you!

Comment: @cactussss As you didn't provide reproducible example of your data I just made may own. ll is list consisting of three list elements, of which each is data frame.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly! As a following up question -- how can I replace the infinite values with zero in the list? I tried `list[is.infinite] == 0` which gave me the following error message "Error in list[is.infinite] : invalid subscript type 'builtin' ". Btw, my list does not consist of dataframe but lists.

Answer (score 2):

Working on @DidzisElferts answer, you can use this

```
lapply(ll, within, z <- (a-b)/c)
```

to add `z` as a new column on each dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ferdinand. But what if the elements of my list are not data frame(there are 23 lists within my list) More specifically, the command `class(list[[1]])` gives me the result `"list"`. Do you have any ideas how to convert them into dataframe effectively? Thanks.

Comment: What I wish to do is just changing the class of the elements of the list but keep the whole data set as grouped (say from a list of 23 lists to a list of 23 dataframes)

Comment: If your list elements are lists themsevlves, with vectors of the same length, you can use `lapply(ll, as.data.frame)` to convert them to dataframes.